# Open and maximise a browser window in OATS Java (not javascript)

Tags: java, oracle, testing, browser, openscript

I am a tester and just installed oracle application test suite to use testing eBus apps

Anyway the only language it supports for coding test scripts (I don't want to use the recorder for a number of reasons).  The problem I am having is that everything I search or google is javascript not java (even googling with -script I still ended up looking at javascript.  This just gets rejected by the oats editor
The only other examples I have seen, appear to be defining a variable then setting the value of that variable as the window they want to maximize.  Aside from the fact that my java skills are not up to doing that - I do not need to do this for a newly opened browser window do I? (The assumption is that this will be the only browser window open (ie test is executed with browser closed)

Is there any easy way to do this?

Below is the very simple initiate of the browser which is generated from a recording plus part of the first step which loads the url the test starts at: (I realize the first step is not complete below -I didn't paste it all, just enough to hopefully allow someone to show me what I need to edit to force the browser to load maximized, or maximize it immediately after loading?

public void initialize() throws Exception {
        browser.launch();

```
}

/**
 * Add code to be executed each iteration for this virtual user.
 */
public void run() throws Exception {
    beginStep("[1] Login (/RF.jsp)", 0);
    {

        web
                .window(2,
                        "/web:window[@index='0' or @title='about:blank']")
                .navigate(
                        "http://somepageiwantolaunch");
        web.window(4, "/web:window[@index='0' or @title='Login']")
                .waitForPage(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you already got the answer for this.. if not this code should help you

```
browser.launch();
DOMBrowser currentExecutionBrowser = web.window("/web:window[@index='0' or @index='1']");
currentExecutionBrowser.maximize();
```

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in the Oracle Functional Tester API Reference which has a build in function called *object*.WindowState It says you can get or set using this function and it has values

```
    0 - Normal, 1- minimized and 2-maximised.
```

Only issue is that these examples look more like VB than Javascript but presumably there is a similar function built into to the Oracle libraries for Java.

I did a quick search for Oracle Openscript API and came up with this [link](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1007868&tstart=1110) which asks for the same thing.  They suggest using Help->Search from within the openscript application and then searching for "openscript API" which should provide a list of the functions available.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To Maximize browser in OATS, follow the below code
Open script ha in built methods which helps coding easy

```
    browser.launch();
    web.window(12, "/web:window[@index='0' or @title='about:blank']").navigate("http://www.google.com/");
    web.window(12, "/web:window[@index='0' or @title='about:blank']").maximize();
```

for more OATS Tips/Tricks follow here
http://www.testinghive.com/category/oracle-application-testing-suite-tips

Answer (score 0):

If it is the only browser window open, you can use the below code. It must be used with caution since the code maximizes any window that is open above the browser window.

```
try {
        Robot a = new Robot();
        a.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        a.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
        a.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);
        a.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        a.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_X);
        a.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_X);
    } catch (AWTException e) {

    }
```